# Loop and number selection issue in Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this rock paper scissors game I am  having some issues, one is it failing to enter the loops of comparing the numbers of the game. But before that I'm not getting it to select a number correctly for the computer to pick what it throws. As I am still learning how to code I would appreciate knowing what the issue is

```
from random import randint

def rock_paper_scissors():
    w = int(input('How many rounds to win? '))
    u = int(0)
    c = int(0)
    r = int(1)
    if c or u < w:
        print ('Round #', r)
        ut = input('Do you throw Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3)? ')
        ct = randint(1, 3)
        print ('Computer threw', ct)
        if ut == ct:
            print (Tie)
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)             
        if ut == 1 and ct == 2:
            print ('Computer wins')
            c += 1
            r =+ 1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)
        if ut == 1 and ct == 3:
            print ('You win')
            u +=1
            r +=1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)            
        if ut == 2 and ct == 1:
            print ('You win')
            u += 1
            r += 1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)             
        if ut == 2 and ct == 3:
            print ('Computer wins')
            c += 1
            r += 1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)             
        if ut == 3 and ct == 1:
            print ('Computer wins')
            c += 1
            r +=1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)             
        if ut == 3 and ct == 2:
            print ('You win')
            u += 1
            r += 1
            print ('Score:'
                   'Computer:', c,
                   'User:', u)             
    if c == w:
        print ('Computer wins')
    if u == w:
        print ('You win')

def main(): 
    print('ROCK PAPER SCISSORS in Python')
    print()
    print('Rules: 1) Rock wins over Scissors.')
    print('       2) Scissors wins over Paper.')
    print('       3) Paper wins over Rock.')

    rock_paper_scissors()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's near the `if c or u` thing.
Try something like `if c < w or u < w:`
Feel free to comment for further info. Good Luck.

Comment: I think that worked but I still have the issue of the computer picking a random number between 1 and 3 for it to compare to the user input.

Comment: @Warmlawpk441 make sure you've imported the library. `from random import randint`